# why SimpleUrHandler class handle class not mapping jsp uir base request

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have  develop a spring mvc program with .jsp uri base request but our handler class give warring

```
Nov 09, 2018 12:04:12 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping for GET /ThirdAppWithUrlFileNameViewController
```

and give 404 exception.other extension it is working only .jsp extension it gives exception

```
//web.xml
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <!-- The front controller of this Spring Web application, responsible for handling all application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <!-- Map all requests to the DispatcherServlet for handling -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring Bean configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd">
<!-- Controller class cfg -->
<bean id="ufvc" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.UrlFilenameViewController"/>
<bean id="stc" class="com.nt.controller.StudentController"/>

<!-- Handler class cfg -->
<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
<property name="mappings" >
<props>
<prop key="/rt.jsp">stc</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>

<!-- ViewResolver cfg -->
<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

index.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<jsp:forward page="rt.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is our controller class configration
StudentController.java

```
package com.nt.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class StudentController extends AbstractController {

    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        return new ModelAndView("info");
    }//handleRequestInternal(-,-)

}//class
```

info.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Id Of The Student :: <% out.print("SIT0123Fg45"); %><br>
Name Of The Student :: <% out.print("Raju Talwar(navik)"); %><br>
Stream Of The Student :: <% out.print("MCA"); %><br>
</body>
</html>
```

/